# $wpdb issue with server memory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function to fetch data from a table on the single-product.php template

```
function get_product_meta( $pid ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM wp_product_feed WHERE product_id = %d', $pid );
    $var = $wpdb->get_row( $query );
    return $var;
}
```

The issue is the server crashes from out of memory.

[image]

Anyone know why or how the best way to troubleshoot the issue? The site crashes before the page loads and cannot ssh into the server to view the logs.

UPDATED THE FUNCTION TO ONLY FETCH ONE COLUMN

```
function get_product_meta( $pid, $key ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT `$key` FROM wp_product_feed WHERE product_id = %d", $pid );
    $var = $wpdb->get_var( $query );
    return $var;
}
```

Still having the same issue

Comment: Are you sure it's connected to the db query? If so, have you tried narrowing down the data that is feteched to just a few or even a single column? Are there large amounts of data stored in that table (maybe one or more BLOBs)?

Comment: Yes i am connected to the DB Query and also tried a single Column and still having the same issue.

Comment: Are you on WP 5.8?  I'm seeing some similar problems doing inserts and updates with WPDB consuming all available memory, this is with small amounts of data, on code that has been running reliably for years.